# Need help in reducing time for graphing a monster function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I'm graphing the following function:

[image: function]

L(l=0) is pretty self explanatory in the code which is piecewise with 2 conditions: B1 and B2.This is my attempt at graphing it (in Python):

```
import numpy as np 
from mpmath import *
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ulist = np.random.uniform(size=40)

sigma = 0.05 

somelist = [] 

def fsubk(t0): 
    somelist.clear()   
    for i in range(0,len(ulist)): 
        somelist.append(float(exp((ulist[i]-t0)/(sigma/sqrt(2)))*nsum(lambda k: exp(-k/(sigma/sqrt(2))),[1,inf]))) 
        somelist.append(float(exp((t0-ulist[i])/(sigma/sqrt(2)))*nsum(lambda k: exp(k/(sigma/sqrt(2))),[-inf,-1]))) 
        if t0 >= ulist[i]:  
            somelist.append(float(exp((ulist[i]-t0)/(sigma/sqrt(2))))) # B1 condition
        else:
            somelist.append(float(exp((t0-ulist[i])/(sigma/sqrt(2))))) # B2 condition
return float(np.sum(somelist)*(1/(sigma*sqrt(2)))+10)

vfunc = np.vectorize(fsubk)
x = np.linspace(0,0.9999999999999,100)
y = vfunc(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I'm looking to optimize my code so that generating the graph is significantly faster. Sympy recommends to use the autowrap module and I tried doing it with binary_function and lambdify (not shown here) but I didn't see noticeable changes.
If anyone can help, that'd be very appreciated!

Comment: As an aside, you cannot use MathJax (or any other LaTeX derivative) on SO outside the math-heavy sites which really need it as it imposes a significant delay on page-load.

Comment: Try to use `enumerate()` rather than `range(len())` . This is a side note, i doubt it would improve the performance. A quick suggestion though, you could add some timers in here to figure out where it begins to slow down, or what is taking so long, this way, you are able to look at individual chunks of code, because it might not be the whole code causing the issue, but rather one particular function or loop.

Comment: Could you somehow thread this? I think by default you can use 1000 or so threads. If you don't care about the order that it returns the numbers in that is.

Comment: What do you guys think about ufunctify from sympy.utilities.autowrap?